# how to work with Custom UserAuthantication in DNN

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6

I have created new login skin object which contain a single hyperlink. this skinobject is placed on another custom sking object. When this login hyperlink is clicked i open a popup a div, this div contains the DNN's built in login control placed in  Desktopmodules/Admin/Autanticationservice/. Now when login module pops up and i click on login button, this hits to the login_clicked event of the DNN's Login module. Here i see through debugging that user passes the authantication but inside this method on the last line "OnUserAuthenticated(args)" does not being called...???Why??? any ideas..???

Comment: plz help i am stuck to this...

Answer (score 2):

I had this one, too, haven't figured out how to fix the real problem, but you can get around it by replacing:

```
UserController.ValidateUser(PortalId, txtUsername.Value, txtPassword.Value, "DNN", string.Empty, PortalSettings.PortalName, IPAddress, ref loginStatus);
```

with

```
UserController.UserLogin(PortalSettings.PortalId, txtUsername.Value, txtPassword.Value, string.Empty, PortalSettings.PortalName, IPAddress, ref loginStatus, false);
```

It will at least log you in then, but you will have to deal with redirecting yourself.

**It is a hack** and I'm not happy with it, but hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, looked long and hard and eventually had to download the full source and follow through the code for login in the full dnn app:

Once I added the following I could successfully authenticate a user:

```
        // from above
        UserController.UserLogin(PortalSettings.PortalId, txtUsername.Value, txtPassword.Value, string.Empty, PortalSettings.PortalName, IPAddress, ref loginStatus, false);
        // login and auth with DNN
        var existingUserEventArgs = new UserAuthenticatedEventArgs(loginUser, loginUser.Username, loginStatus, "DNN");
        existingUserEventArgs.Authenticated = true;
        EventManager.Instance.OnUserAuthenticated(new UserEventArgs { User = loginUser });
        // success - redirect - or what ever
```